# delete mutation returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, express-graphql

I have a list of to-dos where I've successfully managed to add new items and update cache and now working on adding a delete mutation.
My ultimate goal is to return an id from the delete mutation that this id could be used to update the whole list of to-dos on the client side.

I've tried passing an item's id to the mutation but it returns null.

schema

```
type Todo {
  _id: ID!
  todo: String!
}

type RootMutation {
  deleteTodo(_id: ID!): Todo
}
```

resolver

```
  deleteTodo: async function({ _id }, req) {
    return await Todo.deleteOne({ _id });
  }
```

Tested this mutation in the graphql interface at http://localhost:3000/graphql with the following code:

```
mutation {
  deleteTodo (_id: "example0101010101001010101aasdsadasd"){
        _id
    }
}
```

getting this error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Todo._id.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "deleteTodo",
        "_id"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "deleteTodo": null
  }
}
```

As I'm passing an item's id to the mutation it is expected to return the id of this deleted item but I keep getting null.
I suspect there might be a problem with my resolver function.

Link to the github [repo](https://github.com/waegukinScript/nextjs-apollo-graphql-starter)

Comment: It looks like your resolver and function is working as you intended. It seems that your root mutation is returning a Todo object, which no longer exists. You may want to return a boolean instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to use the `deleteOne` method here. Looking at the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts) for `mongoose`, `remove`, `deleteOne` and `deleteMany` do not return the deleted document. Use [`findByIdAndRemove`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) instead, which will return the deleted document, or null if it wasn't found.

Comment: Yes. Basically, the following code solved the problem: 
`const deletedTodo = await Todo.findByIdAndDelete({ _id });  
return { _id: deletedTodo.id,todo: deletedTodo.todo };` 
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!